# Disable Date & Time field - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, script-webpart

I have 3 date fields into my list, but I want to disable one of them.

**Column name** = Fecha

I try to achieve it adding Script Editor like this:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var itemID = $(" input[title='Fecha'] ").attr("id");



var itemCode = itemID.substring(0, itemID.indexOf('$'));



$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='Date']" ).attr('readonly', 'readonly');



$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > a" ).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');



$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateHours']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateMinutes']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>
```

But it just don´t works, I try to debug it into new item view but I cant see code of script I insert into Script Editor, what is wrong there? Regards

Comment: You should wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function{ ..Your code here.. });` then give a try.

Comment: It load correctly, but I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` like Jquery is not loading @PradipR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your js code does not run, because you have added Scrip Editor Web Part to the list view. If you want to disable field in New Item form, you have to modify **Default New Form** and add appropriate code there:
[image: Editing Default New Form]

You can do same thing with Default Edit Form

Comment: Omg you´re right but now I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` like Jquery is not loading

Comment: I tried to recreate it but even I loaded exactly the same jquery file it just worked fine for me. What was the issue?

Comment: I create another  [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224727/getting-undefined-when-trying-to-get-input-textbox-of-datepickerwith)  new issue in js code,