# Getting undefined when trying to get input textbox of DatePicker

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I want to disable Date and Time picker but I can´t get input textbox, I always get `undefined`

**Code**

```
<script>

// Search for the input textbox of DatePicker by its title and get its Item ID 


var itemID = $(" input[title='Fechados'] ").attr("id");

// Trim the Item ID and keep the first part which is common for each element of this DatePicker

var itemCode = itemID.substring(0, itemID.indexOf('$'));

// Set text input to readOnly  

$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='Date']" ).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

// Disable the onclick action on the button

$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dtinput > a" ).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');

// Disable the 2 time select elements

$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateHours']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$( "[id^=" + itemCode + "] td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateMinutes']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

</script>
```

This line always throw me undefined:

```
 var itemID = $(" input[title='Fechados'] ").attr("id");
```

I don´t know why if Title of my column is correctly. Regards

Message received in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

**HTML:**

```
<td class="ms-dtinput">
<label for="Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_$DateTimeFieldDate" style="display:none">Fechados Date</label>
<input type="text" value="31/08/2017" maxlength="45" id="Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_$DateTimeFieldDate" title="Fechados" class="ms-input" autopostback="0">
</td>
```

Comment: Could you show html containing field which id you are trying to get?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my question @rafter13

Answer (score 0):

You can get your input by using his `id` and jQuery `$("#")` selector. You also need to escape special character with `\\` ([See doc](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) :

```
$("#Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_\\$DateTimeFieldDate");
```

Then if you want to disable it you can append `.attr("readonly", true);`

Comment: So instead this line $(" input[title='Fechados'] ").attr("id"); use this? $("#Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_$DateTimeFieldDate").attr("readonly",true);?

Comment: Absolutely, using the id of an element is the best way to select it

Comment: I drop all my script and use only $("#Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_$DateTimeF‌​ieldDate").attr("rea‌​donly",true); but I get Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Fechados_fb10b3d7-d448-474d-af75-13c64038c3e5_$DateTimeF‌​ieldDate

Comment: Well, that's because you have a "$" in your id, see my edited post.

Comment: If there are no more fields with the same title on the page, your selector based on 'title' attribute was just fine. Using Id which is generated by SP and completely unclear is not a better idea in my opinion.